# Bar code scanner app - Customize Shopsavvy

Tags: ios, barcode, barcode-scanner

I need an iPhone bar-code scanner app which can be customized to link with my own barcode database for our products. Is there any way I can customize one of the softwares listed here:  http://gizmodo.com/5713768/the-best-barcode-scanner-apps
so that it can scan the barcodes of our company products ?

The barcodes on the products that need to be scanned have been printed in our machine.

Comment: yes, you can customize those for your purpose. If you like a free one, take a look at zbar, i had implemented it few times and it worked surprisingly good. Scanning the barcode gives you the number underneath, which you will then use to lookup the item in your internal database. Take a look here as well, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728642/redlaser-sdk-alternatives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a few sites which offer barcode SDKs

http://shopsavvy.mobi/developers/

http://www.quickmark.com.tw/en/basic/SDK.asp

https://github.com/netshade/Cocoa-Touch-Barcodes

http://redlaser.com/developers/

http://www.scandit.com/barcode-scanner-sdk/